# PHP Regex Last Entry with Sperators

Tags: php, regex

Sorry my regex skills are horrible.  I am trying figure out how to just get the final entry in a text file i am manipulating. So the line of data is...

> Paint & Maintenance///Cleaners, Soaps & Polishes///Vinyl Cleaners & Protectors

I need only the string of data that shows up after the last "///" (Vinyl Cleaners & Protectors) but the number of separators ("///") will vary each time.

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say number of separators will change, do you mean, "the separator will always be three slashes but there could be any number of fields on the line" or, "the separator could be any number of slashes?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need regex for that:

```
$delim = '///';
$str = 'Paint & Maintenance///Cleaners, Soaps & Polishes///Vinyl Cleaners / Protectors';
$str = substr($str, strrpos($str, $delim)+strlen($delim));
```

**Edit:**

Using native string functions is **much** faster than a regex expression. As a general rule, only use regex when absolutely necessary.

Comment: That's great until `$str = 'Paint & Maintenance///Cleaners, Soaps & Polishes///Vinyl Cleaners / Protectors'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$last_item = array_pop(preg_split('|///|', $str));
```

(Edit: I think I misunderstood your statement about number of separators, adjusted.)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\/+(.+)$/',$in,$m); echo $m[1];
```